# How do I create a dynamic control (text box) in C# and how to set the initial the value

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, textbox, controls

How do I create a dynamic control (text box) in C# upon button click?
How to retain the dynamic control after post back?
How to keep the text box's value?

I tried the following code,
buttonclick:

```
List<string> lstDynId;
int iUnique = 0;
string strDynId = "tbx";

if (ViewState["strVS_DynamicIds"] != null)
{
    DisplayRTControls();
    lstDynId = (List<string>)ViewState["strVS_DynamicIds"];
    //get the Id of last textbox
    string strLastControlId = lstDynId[lstDynId.Count - 1];
    // get the substring starting after "tbx"
    string strIdNumber = strLastControlId.Substring(3);
    iUnique = int.Parse(strIdNumber) + 1;
}
else
{
    lstDynId = new List<string>();
}
strDynId += iUnique;
TextBox tbx = new TextBox();
tbx.ID = strDynId;
tbx.EnableViewState = true;
HtmlTableRow new1 = new HtmlTableRow();
new1.ID = "row" + strDynId;
HtmlTableCell cell1 = new HtmlTableCell();
cell1.ID = "cell" + strDynId;
TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
cell1.Controls.Add(tbx);
new1.Cells.Add(cell1);
try
{
    tbl.Rows.Add(new1);
}
catch
{
}
lstDynId.Add(strDynId);
ViewState["strVS_DynamicIds"] = lstDynId;

private void DisplayRTControls()
{
    if (ViewState["strVS_DynamicIds"] != null)
    {
        List<string> lstDynId = (List<string>)ViewState["strVS_DynamicIds"];
        foreach (string strId in lstDynId)
        {
            TextBox tbx = new TextBox();
            tbx.ID = strId;
            tbx.Text = tbx.Text;
            tbx.EnableViewState = true;
            HtmlTableRow new1 = new HtmlTableRow();
            HtmlTableCell cell1 = new HtmlTableCell();
            TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
            cell1.Controls.Add(tbx);
            new1.Cells.Add(cell1);
            tbl.Rows.Add(new1);
        }
    }      
}
```

The problem is that I can't retain the text box value? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following:

.aspx page:

```
<div>
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Add Textbox" />
   <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
   </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

.aspx.cs page:

private List textboxes;

```
protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PreRender += new EventHandler(_Default_PreRender);

    textboxes = new List<TextBox>();

    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        //recreate Textboxes
        int count = Int32.Parse(ViewState["tbCount"].ToString());

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.ID = "tb" + i;

            Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);

            textboxes.Add(tb);

            tb.Text = Request.Form[tb.ClientID];
        }
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create new textbox
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.ID = "tb" + textboxes.Count;

    Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);

    textboxes.Add(tb);        
}

void _Default_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //remember how many textboxes we had
    ViewState["tbCount"] = textboxes.Count;
}
```

For detailed source code see original blog post [here](http://www.dotnetobject.com/Thread-creating-and-maintain-data-in-dynamic-textbox-using-asp-net) .

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using server side control for your case will be a bit trick because you would have to recreate them in Page Init event in order to they get the posted values in the `Text` property.

And recovering server side control values through `Request.Form` is trouble too because we don't know the HTML `name` attribute for each textbox after the PostBack, and it would depend of your controls tree.

You can go with `HtmlInputText` instead of `TextBox`:

```
HtmlInputText tbx = new HtmlInputText();
tbx.ID = strDynId;
tbx.Name = strDynId;
```

To recover the value upon a PostBack just do:

```
Request.Form[strDynId]
```

If you want to keep the `TextBox` you will have to figure a way of storing their `UniqueId`s after adding them to the `Controls` collection or hardcode the names in `Request.Form` calls.

Answer (score 0):

For retaining the textbox value, Consider the example here:-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalAmt" runat="server" class="txtfld-popup2" MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox>
```

on Code behind page load, you just need to add the below line code:-

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        TextBox txtValue = new TextBox();
        txtValue.Text = Request.Form[txtTotalAmt.UniqueID];
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works